# $2^a$ divides an expression for any value of a

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

show that we can get an "$x$" for every "$a$" such that
$15^2(15^x-5^{x-2}-3^{x-2}) \equiv  -1 \pmod{2^a}$

Comment: please don't give solution, can you give me some hint? i have no idea how to proceed. i saw if we replace 5 and 3 by some other odd numbers(not every odd numbers maybe prime only) and 15 by those two odd number multiplied we can get a solution.

Comment: It seems like noting $15 = 2^4 -1$ might be a good start.

Comment: Just from pattern-matching it seems like they might want you to use the identity $15^2(15^x-5^{x-2}-3^{x-2})+1 = (3^{x - 2} 15^2 - 1) (5^{x - 2} 15^2 - 1)$.